# chrome doesn't show download progress nodejs api

Tags: node.js

Why does it not show the download progress for a file that I am serving through nodejs? Does it have to do with how I pipe in chunks to the HTTP response? The file must be served through streaming, since it is very large. I have tried to modify the headers to include content-length, but then I got a 502 error from my server.

```
app.get("/download", function(res, res){
    const fs = require("fs");
    var file = fs.createReadStream("bigfile.txt");
    res.set({"Content-Disposition" : "attachment; filename=bigfile.txt", "Content-Type" : "application/octet-stream"});
    file.pipe(res);
});
```

[image]

Comment: It's [`Content-Length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Length), any more details on the 502?

Comment: I'm proxying it, on my proxy I get 502 (The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.). When I try it directly, it downloads but doesn't show the size still

Comment: Have you tried `res.download` helper? At least there is some additional error handling that needs to be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`res.download()` solve your problem. It internally uses `res.sendFile()` to transfer the file. `sendFile` does some extra stuff, like setting the proper HTTP Content-Type header based on the filename and `Content-Length`. When you set  `"Content-Type" : "application/octet-stream"` extra header  `"Transfer-Encoding: chunked"` Will be added by express.

> Chunked Data is sent in a series of chunks. The Content-Length header
>   is omitted in this case and at the beginning of each chunk you need to
>   add the length of the current chunk in hexadecimal format, followed by
>   '\r\n' and then the chunk itself, followed by another '\r\n'. The
>   terminating chunk is a regular chunk, with the exception that its
>   length is zero. It is followed by the trailer, which consists of a
>   (possibly empty) sequence of entity header fields.
>   read more about Transfer-Encoding here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Transfer-Encoding.

Response header when we use `res.download()`

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Express
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="sample.txt"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Cache-Control: public, max-age=0
Last-Modified: Mon, 30 Sep 2019 09:39:48 GMT
ETag: W/"331822b1-16d818a4ea0"
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 857219761
Date: Wed, 05 Feb 2020 20:55:28 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
```

Response header when you manually set `"Content-Disposition" : "attachment; filename=bigfile.txt"` and `"Content-Type" : "application/octet-stream"`

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Express
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=bigfile.txt
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Date: Wed, 05 Feb 2020 20:57:55 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

You can test it yourself also here is basic code:
**app.js**

```
  const express = require('express');
    const app = express();
    const http = require('http');
    const fs = require('fs');
    app.get("/",function(req,res){
     res.sendFile(__dirname+'/index.html'); 
    })
    app.get('/download', function(req, res){
      const file = `${__dirname}/sample.txt`;
      res.download(file); // Set disposition and send it.
      // const file = fs.createReadStream(`${__dirname}/sample.txt`);
       // res.set({"Content-Disposition" : "attachment; filename=bigfile.txt", 
    //"Content-Type" : "application/octet-stream"});
       // file.pipe(res);
    });
  http.createServer(app).listen(80);
```

**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello!</title>
</head>
<body>
<h3>Hello HTTP!</h3>

<a href="http://localhost/download">download</a>
</body>
</html>
```

**Run and Check response header in both cases in Chrome**

> **Important**  If you are using a reverse proxy like `nginx` for large file you might have to configure this:
>   http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_max_temp_file_size